# How to get attributes for HashMap value?

Tags: java, attributes, hashmap

"my" code:

```
public void iterateHashmap2() {
    HashMap hashmap = this.media;
    Iterator it = hashmap.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Object key = it.next();
        Object val = hashmap.get(key);
            // doesn't work..
        System.out.println(val.getAttribute);
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I get the attributes that the value contains. The value is a class I made myself, which contains 4 Strings and another class I made, as attributes.
(What I want to do is iterate through a hashmap and compare the String of an attribute that is stored in the value with input data.. so I need to be able to access the attributes in the values of the hashmap..hope that makes sense..)

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts. You can now edit your question and leave comments under answers (please do, instead of posting comments as answers).

Answer (score 5):

You access values in a map by providing a key:

```
// create a map
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
// store a value
map.put("key", someObject);
// retrieve a value
MyObject someObject2 = map.get("key");
```

You can also use

- `map.keySet()` to retrieve all keys
- `map.values()` to retrieve all values, without keys
- `map.entrySet()` to retrieve all Mappings. Each Entry represents one key mapped to one value.

a) In my code I use [Java Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), because that has been the standard way to do it for at least 5 years now.
b) You should consider reading [The Map Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) from the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

a): If you are using **JDK1.5** or higher, please use generic and enhanced loop. The code will much simpler and safer:

```
 for(Map.Entry<Key, YourObj> entry: this.media.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().getAttribute());
 }
```

b): If you have to use **JDK1.4** or lower, you have to cast your object: `((YourObj)val).getAttribute();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Object val = hashmap.get(key);
            // doesn't work..
System.out.println(val.getAttribute());
```

The problem here is that Java is statically typed, which means you would need to cast `val` in order to access non-Object methods. You need to cast `val` as the type actually in the hashmap, as you're not using generics.

`MyClass val = (MyClass) hashmap.get(key);`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
Object val = hashmap.get(key);
```

to this line:

```
YourClass val = (YourClass) hashmap.get(key);
```

Since you are getting an Object type you cannot just call your class's method without first casting it correctly.

Btw you should seriously consider using [Java Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: You val is still Object, this won't help.

Comment: Yes realized and fixed just before your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a cast to a your target object's type. Like:

```
YourObject val = (YourObject) hashmap.get(key);
```

But ...

- Your Map should be generic like `Map<KeyClass, ValueClass>`
- There is better way to iterate over a `Map`:

Example:

```
for (Map.Entry<KeyClass, ValueClass> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    KeyClass key = entry.getKey();
    ValueClass val = entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to cast the value mapped to the key in the HashMap why not use generics to achieve that:

```
public void iterateHashmap2() {
    HashMap<Object,YourClass> hashmap = this.media;
    Iterator<YourClass> it = hashmap.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Object key = it.next();
        YourClass val = hashmap.get(key);
            // if YourClass has a getAttribute() method then this will work
        System.out.println(val.getAttribute());
    }
}
```

Also note that it's always good practice to work at interface level -- so this line:

```
    HashMap<Object,YourClass> hashmap = this.media;
```

should be

```
    Map<Object,YourClass> hashmap = this.media;
```